# Program won't quit after 10 integers or 0 have been entered

Tags: java

Can someone help explain to me why my program won't terminate after either "0" or 10 integers have been entered? It's supposed to after, but it won't and keeps going even after either condition to quit have been met. It compiles correctly and doesn't give me any errors, so I think it has to do with my loops but I don't know what's wrong...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab11
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    int intArray[] = new int[10];
    int size = 0;
    int userInt;

    do
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer in the array, or enter  '0' to quit:" + " ");
            userInt = scan.nextInt();

            if (userInt != 0)
            {
                intArray[size] = userInt;
                size++;
            }
        }
        while (size <= intArray.length);

        System.out.println(sum(intArray, size));
        System.out.println(max(intArray, size));
        System.out.println(min(intArray, size));
        System.out.println(average(intArray, size));
        System.out.println(stringToArray(intArray, size));
    }
    while (userInt !=0);

}

public static int sum(int intArray[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a <= size; a++)
    {
        sum = sum + intArray[size];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int max(int intArray[], int size)
{
    int max = intArray[0];

    for (int b = 1; b <= size; b++)
    {
        if (intArray[size] > max)
        {
            max = intArray[size];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int min(int intArray[], int size)
{
    int min = intArray[0];

    for (int c = 1; c <= size; c++)
    {
        if (intArray[size] < min)
        {
            min = intArray[size];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

public static double average(int intArray[], int size)
{
    double total = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for (double element : intArray)
    {
        total = total + element;
    }

    if (intArray.length > 0)
    {
        average = total / intArray.length;
    }
    return average;
}

public static String stringToArray(int intArray[], int size)
{
    String stringArray = "";

    for (int d = 1; d <= size; d++)
    {
        stringArray = intArray.toString();
    }
    return stringArray;
}
}
```

Comment: when zer ois entered the loop doesn't stop because `while (size <= intArray.length);` doesn't test for it and the declaration of size=0 should be INSIDE the outside do loop.

Comment: Because you never change `size`. Honestly, you really need to learn some basic debugging. Asking people rather than figuring it out will get you exactly nowhere.

Comment: I'm completely new to Java and I've tried to fix it before I asked. The current loops I'm using are what I got after re-editing. I am aware that asking before trying will do nothing, and there is an increment for size but I'm just not aware of why it's not working.

Comment: @Kirikiriyu A useful technique for getting to the bottom of things like this is to add temporary `System.out.println`'s in key places that help you trace the path your code is following. If you are using an IDE with a built-in debugger (like NetBeans or Eclipse), running it in the debugger is invaluable as well, and you can step through code one line at a time to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement that tests for 0 is sandwiched in a do/while, and the do/while will loop your checker until your if statement is true. Place it outside your loop.

Edit: Heh the main method bit was for C, not java :)